# Bad writing in GoogleSheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've one sheet that works as database which gets the data from too many different sheets. It works in that logic, I've multiple sheets that everyone is filling the data in and then click on a button to trigger a script that takes the data and paste it in the database sheet, and sends an email with the data to the relevant stakeholder.
The issue I'm facing is that, if two sheets triggered the script at the same time one sheet will overwrite the other one because both were triggered at the same time and both were targeting the same row in the database.

I've tried the lock methods as well but it will not work because those are multiple sheets and multiple scripts, and tried to assign a ticket number property but it will not work as well because every script is operating on different sheet. thought of library but it will not be as fast as the normal script.

Comment: You say `I've one sheet that works as database which gets the data from too many different sheets.`  do you mean to say this `I've one spreadsheet that works as database which gets the data from many different Spreadsheets.`?

Comment: I think you could do it with one standalone webapp?

Comment: Have you tried using a third spreadsheet with all scripts using the append method to ether create an update queue or use timestamps and sheet names to auto flag when this has likely happened?

Comment: @Cooper Yes, that's what I meant.
I'm worried about the script performance as well because more than 25 people are using it in the normal day.

Comment: @Hink Can you elaborate more on this idea? I've already a timestamp in my data but not sure how to setup a queue on this one

Comment: Perhaps you should use a database they have all sorts of locking features.

Comment: Any recommendations on a free usage one?
We've Presto as well in the org, but still not sure how much time is needed to setup Presto with the script